# Connect to a distant directory via SMB - Failed to retrieve share list from server

Tags: fedora, smb

I tried to connect to a distant directory via SMB. The directory is hosted in 10.1.13.211.

The execution of `smbclient -L 10.1.80.118 --debuglevel 2` returns : `protocol negotiation failed: NT_STATUS_CONNECTION_DISCONNECTED`

Typing `smb://10.1.80.118` in Files Browser (Nautilus) returns : `Failed to retrieve share list from server: Software caused connection abort`

Answer (score 1):

In the file /etc/samba/smb.conf, under the section [global], below the workgroup line add this two lines :

```
client min protocol = NT1
client max protocol = SMB3
```

**Explanation :**

Fedora uses a samba client (smbclient) to connect using the SMB protocol.
For recent versions of Fedora (Fedora 32 For Me), the used `smbclient` package has a version > 4.11.
There is a major change in this version, the NT1 protocol is no longer the client minimum protocol used. So to connect to a remote computer using NT1 the client minimum protocol should be modified.

> SMB1 is disabled by default.
>     The defaults of 'client min protocol' and 'server min protocol' have been changed to SMB2_02.
>   This means clients without support for SMB2 or SMB3 are no longer able to connect to smbd (by default).
>   It also means client tools like smbclient and other, as well as applications making use of libsmbclient are no longer able to connect to servers without SMB2 or SMB3 support (by default).
>   It's still possible to allow SMB1 dialects, e.g. NT1, LANMAN2 and LANMAN1 for client and server, as well as CORE and COREPLUS on the client.
>   [Source](https://www.samba.org/samba/history/samba-4.11.0.html)

Comment: I had the same problem on Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS, when I tried to connect to a USB drive plugged in a router, shared with SMB. 
First I had to install the samba client `sudo apt install samba` (though I could connect to other smb server before), then edit the smb.conf like above and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found adding these lines fixed it for me:

```
client min protocol = CORE
server min protocol = CORE
```